# Threading error in datagrid combobox control

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagrid control in my project which has a combobox control manually filled with data, however the problem is that when I try to edit this value while adding a new row, I get a threading state exception:

[image: DataGrid Error]

The programs entry point method is set with the STAThread attribute, I have even placed the attribute on the method that calls the form with the control, still to no avail. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code for us to help you.

Comment: @Tejs: Exactly, I was thinking about that but I didn't know what part of the code will be relevant by csharptest.net cleared up my problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The programs entry point method is set with the STAThread attribute...

This only applies to the main thread of the application.  You must also be careful about threads you create that display this dialog box.  For example:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
```

If you did not directly create the thread you will need to change the code more drastically.  For example if you are displaying the dialog box in Delegate.BeginInvoke() call, the thread will be the application's default thread pool.  Since you do not have control over that thread's creation you can not create it as an STA thread.  Instead you will need to create your own thread as above to display the dialog box.

Comment: superb, I was setting the attribute on the thread creation method instead of the thread itself, thanks!